# How to query large amount of data from mysql to website

Tags: php, mysql, web, bigdata

i am making a weatherstation that logs data every second to a mysql database (on my website). Then i have a website that makes graphs from the data, depending on the time interval selection and the selected sensors.

The problem is that i would like to be able to show big time intervals but when there is to much data my website don't work anymore. (i also got ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) I already added index to my sql columns.

Do you know a way to display large data from mySQL to a website?

Comment: maybe a time series database would be more appropriate.

Comment: MySQL is not the best tool for every job. For large streaming data sets, consider a database optimized for that use case, like [Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html). If you're stuck with MySQL, you'll not only need to *tune your server*, but you will probably need to use tools like partitioning to keep your data sets more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL...

Build and maintain [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

If you will be graphing for a year, you might not want more than 356 rows in the summary table for a given sensor.  But then, you might want hi and lo (for, say, temperature).

For more general use, an hourly row might be adequate for weather sensors.

Also, see my unfinished blog on sensor data:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor